# segmentation fault In c solving the addition of big numbers

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Today I started to follow the hacker rank. The question is bellow.

Calculate and print the sum of the elements in an array, keeping in mind that some of those integers may be quite large.
Input Format 
The first line of the input consists of an integer

. 
The next line contains

space-separated integers contained in the array. 
Output Format
Print the integer sum of the elements in the array.
Constraints

Sample Input

```
5
1000000001 1000000002 1000000003 1000000004 1000000005
Output 
5000000015
```

Note : When we add several integer values, the resulting sum might exceed the above range. You might need to use long long int in C/C++ or long data type in Java to store such sums.

The answer I gave is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (){
    int n ;
    int arr1[n];
    long long int arrcount ;
    scanf("%d" , n);
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        scanf("%d" , &arr1[n]);
    }
    for( int i = 0; i <=n; i++) {
        arrcount = arrcount + arr1[n];
    }
    printf("%li" , arrcount);
}
```

But the compiler message was " Segmentation fault"

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting order of statements:

```
int n ;
int arr1[n];
long long int arrcount ;
scanf("%d" , n);
```

If you're using `n` to set the array size on the second line, but only providing a value *to* `n` on the fourth line, what value do you think is being used for the size of the array?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your for loops.  If an array is zero indexed, what is the last element of your array?

From the code you provided, you are iterating i from 0-5 when n = 5.  How many elements are you reading in and how many are you adding to your total?